# How to bold the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets Script, how do I format a variable that uses `.getValue()` in bold in HTML?

For instance:

```
var test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Portfolio").getRange("A1").getValue();
var html = "<strong> test </strong>"
```

Comment: Where are you putting this HTML? If you're using an HTML string somewhere else (for example in `HtmlService`) you need to concatenate the string with the `+` operator; ie `var html = "<strong> " + test + " </strong>"`.

Comment: That's perfect - exactly what I was looking for, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I think that there are no "bold values". But you can format the range bold with the method [setFontWeight](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontWeight(String)) in the Range class. So in your example:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Portfolio");
var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
cell.setFontWeight("bold");
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You need to use the `+` operator to concatenate a string.*

#### Code Fix:

```
var html = "<strong> test </strong>"
```

should be:

```
var html = "<strong> " + test + " </strong>"
```

#### References:

- [JavaScript Operators - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)